# How to extract data from HtmlTable in C# and arrange in a row?

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack, webscarab

I want to extract data from HTMLTable row by row. But I'm facing problems in separating columns in the rows. The code I'm using below gives me each cell in a single line. But I want each row in 1 line then another. how can I do that?

```cs
HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[" + tableCounter + "]");
foreach (var cell in table.SelectNodes(".//tr/td"))
{

    string someVariable = cell.InnerText;
    ReportFileWriter(someVariable);

}
tableCounter++;
```

This is the output I get from this code:

[The Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmqFL.png)

and the original table is like this:

[The Original Html Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkwv7.png)

and the output I want is to have spaces between columns:

[The Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyEsM.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't know your specific website, I used the following code to parse the

html table.

You need install Nuget -> HtmlAgilityPack.
Code:

```
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            string page = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.mufap.com.pk/payout-report.php?tab=01");

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(page);

            List<List<string>> table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='mydata']")
                        .Descendants("tr")
                        .Skip(1)
                        .Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() > 1)
                        .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
                        .ToList();
             string result = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in table[0])
        {
            result = result + "        " + item;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The first row in website:

[image]

The result you will get:
[image]

Comment: abl Cash Fund              Money Markey         Jul 31, 2010 

how to fetch data like this? in a single row

Comment: I have updated my code, you can check if it is helpful for you.